# TFS new state for Features and kanban board

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to add a new custom state for features on TFS (v15.117.27024.0), I have edited the XML file, adding new state value and adding all transitions.

Basically I want to add an extra state "Approved" in between "New" and "In Progress". So Feature flow will be like this New->Approved->In Progress->Done

After apply the changes I can see the new state showing up on Feature template dropdown (screenshot 1) but when I try to customize the Kanban board I can't see the new state (only in progress and new are showing up as per screenshot 2).

What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio does your TFS question apply to?

Comment: Sorry I didnt add it is Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 15.117.27024.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export ProcessConfiguration.xml file with the command below:

```
witadmin exportprocessconfig /collection:http://TFS2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:teamProject /f:ProcessConfiguration.xml
```

And add `<State type="InProgress" value="Approved" />` in Feature's portfolioBacklog. Check below for detailed inforamtion:

```
<PortfolioBacklog category="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" parent="Microsoft.EpicCategory" pluralName="Features" singularName="Feature" workItemCountLimit="1000">
      <AddPanel>
        <Fields>
          <Field refname="System.Title" />
        </Fields>
      </AddPanel>
      <Columns>
        <Column width="100" refname="System.WorkItemType" />
        <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
        <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
        <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" />
        <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue" />
        <Column width="100" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea" />
        <Column width="200" refname="System.Tags" />
      </Columns>
      <States>
        <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
        <State type="InProgress" value="In Progress" />
<State type="InProgress" value="Approved" />
        <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
      </States>
    </PortfolioBacklog>
```

Then, import ProcessConfiguration.xml file with the command below:

```
witadmin importprocessconfig /collection:http://TFS2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:teamProject /f:ProcessConfiguration.xml
```

In this way, you'll see the new state:

[image]

Comment: You don't mention it, but you've got to actually modify the column mappings manually in the UI after the `importprocessconfig` step. I expected the columns to show up immediately.